# How can i make a sum and a multiplication of 2 big numbers without using "long"?

Tags: c++

how can i make a sum and a multiplication of 2 big numbers without using "long"?

its would have to be with arrays right? 
So.. imagine im doing the sum of 18+18:

```
 18
+15
array1 (1,8)
array2 (1,5)
```

i'd need to go at it column by colmn ..8+5=13 --> 3 and 1+1+1( the 3rd '1' would be from the overflow).

..So i'd need to do that for every element in the array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vectors.h>

int main()
{

int array1 ???
int array2 ???

printf("first number");
scanf();

printf("second number");
scanf();


printf("To Sum Enter 'S', to Multiply Enter 'M'");
scanf();


If(M){
```

//the bellow code is wrong, because i would still have to use the "long" atribute...

```
 while(i=1,i<LA2,i++){
while(j=1,j<LA1,j++){
    A1[i]*A2[j]*10^(i+j-2);

            }
            }
   }

If(S){

 while(i=1,i<LA2,i++){
while(j=1,j<LA1,j++){
    A1[i]*A2[j]*10 pow(i+j-2);
```

//cant do this with pow() because i cant use "long", that means ill have to do it element by element in the arrays and present the result in a 3rd array

```
        }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: So, are you talking about "big numbers"? By the way, I take it you don't really mean ^ in your code, as that does "xor", and you seem to mean "to the power of", which is either the function pow()  for floatin point input, or you have to write your own [I think].

Comment: What's your actual question? If it's "can I use arrays of digits to represent large integers", then yes, that's a good implementation.

Comment: the '^' was suposed to be pow(), thanks for the atention

Comment: Get Knuth volume 2 from your library. It covers these topics.

Comment: my question is "how can i make a sum/multiplication with 2 numbers stored in an array", i know it is possible, im just not being able to do it myself (and with the deadline closing in im in trouble..)

Comment: +1 I was thinking of Knuth's 2nd volume when I posted an answer to this question @KevinA.Naudé

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `struct` with two integers if you don't want to use a `long`.

Like this:

```
struct BigInteger{
  int lowerInt;
  int upperInt;
};
```

And then you can add, subtract, multiply or divide these structures according to the various algorithms. For example to multiply you can use the Shift-And-Add multiplier algorithm.

But doing this has serious performance issues. Use the full language instead of limiting yourself.

PS: what language problem is it? C or C++?

Comment: c++, and im not suposed to do it with longs.. ill have to do it as if the numbers could be infinite, so ill have to add/multiply element by element

Comment: to do it element by element, do it bytewise. I remember doing something similar with Intel 8085 processors, where I only had 8 bits to represent an integer, and multiplication required 16 bits(for which we flooded the integer to a consecutive location

Comment: further, bitwise multiplication will be addition multiple times, generating a carry of 1 or 0. That's the beauty of binary, the carry generated is never greater than 1. @jony

Comment: my initial idea was to sum/multiply the elements in side of 2 arrays, and writing the resulting elements in a new array

Comment: same thing, arrays = consecutive locations.

Comment: you may be onto something there, i'll take what ever is simpler

Comment: Can you write a code for that? in theory it seems simple, but my programing skills are failing me :( - and sorry for asking for spoonfeeding like this.. im just overwhelmed with projects and exams and its driving me insane